# Reminders/notifications frameworks in iOS (5?)

Tags: ios, notifications, reminders

I'm looking for some guidelines for notifications/remeinders in iOS.

For android, there is the status bar notifications (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) so I'm wondering if there is something similar for iOS 5?

searching the apple docs for notifications yields results that seem to point to system level notifications,etc. Not user facing notifications (like how android does it).

If what I'm looking for doesn't really exist then are there a set of best practices or existing code on github,etc?

Some background:

- i'm maintaining an app that has quite a few notifcations being rendered as modal popups, obviously this horrible when you have more than 3 so I'm looking for other solutions.
- i'm new to iOS dev.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).